# 3 bugs after starting Marionnet 0.90.6 and cant add Machine in new project

Tags: 13.04

I need to make simple project in Marionnet- virtual network.
I have no experience with Marionnet and minimal experience with Ubuntu/Linux.

After installing and starting Marionnet there are 3 errors:

Unsatisfied dependency:

1. You don't have a default UML kernel for virtual computers
   Continuing anyway, but *some important features will be missing*.
2. You don't have a default filesystem for virtual routers
   Continuing anyway, but *some important features will be missing*.
3. You don't have a default filesystem for virtual computers
   Continuing anyway, but *some important features will be missing*.

Marionet>Project>New then Marionnet crashes.

After restart Ubuntu same errors appears, but this time i can create new project and add every items (Hub, Switch, Cable) except Machine.

Could someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you had built/downloaded only binaries of Marionnet. This tool requires also images of virtual router and virtul workstation. I'm not sure about the UML error, but please follow the steps described here: [marionnet_from_scratch](http://www.marionnet.org/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation%3amarionnet_from_scratch). This script does all the checks, installs and downloads. Good luck wit your project.

Comment: I had installed it today once more following these steps. The instalation finished "succes" and after launch marionnet same errors occur.

Comment: Can you provide installation log?